# Django: saving into model field

Tags: django, forms, view, save, models

another django question. I have a edit form like this. Look at current_status in the code.

It has been updated:

```
def edit_item(request, client_id = 0, item_id = 0):
    client = None
    item = None
    status = None
    contact = None
    status_id = request.POST.get('status_id', None)
    contact_id = request.POST.get('contact_id', None)
    save_item = request.POST.get('save_item', None)
    save_status = request.POST.get('save_status', None)
    try:
        client = models.Client.objects.get(pk = client_id)
        item = models.StorageItem.objects.get(pk = item_id)
    except:
        return HttpResponseNotFound()
    try:
        status = models.Status.objects.get(pk = status_id)
        contact = models.Contact.objects.get(pk = contact_id)
    except:
        pass
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = forms.ItemForm(request.POST, instance = item)
        if form.is_valid() and save_item is not None:
            form.save(True)
            request.user.message_set.create(message = "Item {0} has been updated successfully.".format(item.tiptop_id))
            return HttpResponse("<script language=\"javascript\" type=\"text/javascript\">window.opener.location = window.opener.location; window.close();</script>")

        if status is not None and contact is not None and save_status is not None:
            current_status = models.ItemStatusHistory(item = item, contact = contact, status = status,
                                                          user = request.user)
            item.current_item_status_date = date.today()
            item.save()
            current_status.save()
            request.user.message_set.create(message = "Item status has been updated successfully.")
    else:
        form = forms.ItemForm(instance = item)
        title = str(client) + ' : Edit Item'
    status_list = models.Status.objects.all()
    return render_to_response('edit_item.html', {'form':form, 'title':title, 'status_list':status_list, 'item':item}, context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

`current_status` save's the latest date of when the form is edited. What I ALSO want to do is to save this value into this models field.

```
  class StorageItem(models.Model):
       current_item_status_date = models.DateField()
```

Comment: Sorry, but I think your question is really not understandable in any kind :-) Could you break down the question in another way, ripping of the code from your first block that isn't relevant to the question etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is `ItemForm` a ModelForm (see [Django Model Forms](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/))?

If so `form.save()` will return a model instance. Then you can edit its fields if you need to. For example.

```
my_obj = form.save()
my_obj.current_item_status_date = datetime.date.today()
my_obj.save()
```

If not, then simply create a new instance of your model and save the field value.

```
my_obj = StorageItem(current_item_status_date=datetime.date.today())
my_obj.save()
```

Comment: I get this error when I try to do the second method. "method_descriptor' object has no attribute 'now'". Just to remind you I am using a datefield not datetimeField.

Comment: OK an update. 1st method gave me this error: "The StorageItem could not be changed because the data didn't validate." 2nd method gave me this error:  (1048, "Column 'type_id' cannot be null"). Not really sure why type_id is affected.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I am used to work with datetime.datetime instead of date.

Comment: It should be datetime.date.today() - fixed it above

Comment: about ""Column 'type_id' cannot be null"). Not really sure why type_id is affected". How does your whole model looks like? If you got a field called 'type_id' and its field attribute is not 'null=True' then you have to set it when creating a new instance of the model.

Comment: I also see in your example you actually have 'item' which is already a StorageItem instance. So you just need to to 'item.current_item_status_date = datetime.date.today()' and then 'item.save()' if everything is successful.

Comment: For some unknown reason, Typing item.current_item_status_date = date.today()' and then 'item.save() in views does not save in the current_item_status-date. Look at the update code. See what could be the problem now.

Comment: Actually I think it has worked. I have to paste tem.current_item_status_date = datetime.date.today()' and 'item.save()' BEFORE form.save(true).